# Unable to parse a difficult to understand html file in r

Tags: r, html-parsing, rvest, html-nodes

It's been a while since I visited stackoverflow,
I have a problem with parsing a html file.
I am trying to parse the following link

```
edata <- read_html("https://mmiconnect.in/app/ep-2022/registration/show-catalogue")
```

But I am not able to parse the html file using html_nodes, I tried all possible class names, but for no result.

I am trying to get all the company names, that participated in the EXPO, I tried various "class",

```
html_nodes('.fuse-widget-front .mat-elevation-z4 .m-2 .bg-white')
```

But for any results.

[image: The company names that I am trying to download]

Comment: What is happening? What exactly trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to parse the html with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://mmiconnect.in/app/ep-2022/registration/show-catalogue"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
htmltxt <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
read_html(htmltxt) %>% html_node(xpath = '//*/img') %>% html_attr('src')

[1] "https://mmiconnectstorage.azureedge.net/global-manual-upload/ep-2022-visitor-reg-banner.jpg"
```